# azuresphere real-time applications -- generating .image files from compatible, pre-built ELF (.out) files

Tags: azure-sphere

i have a separate build-flow that can produce .out files for the MT3620/M4 core using the same gcc-arm compiler....  for reasons beyond the scope of this question, it's not practical for me to migrate this build-flow into cmake....

once i generate the .out file, my thinking was to simply envelop it within a project structure identical to the samples -- with an conforming app_manifest.json file....  from here, i could effectively run just the final step of the cmake build -- which generates the image package....

before i go down this path, is there anything obvious i'm missing here????

Answer (score 0):

As of today you will need to decide to install [Azure Sphere SDK Preview for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/install-sdk#azure-sphere-sdk-preview-for-visual-studio) or [Azure Sphere SDK Preview for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/install-sdk#azure-sphere-sdk-preview-for-windows) (You cannot install both SDKs on the same PC.)

To develop applications, however, you need to set up your development environment and possibly install additional tools. The Azure Sphere SDK for Windows supports development with the CLI only. If you've installed this version of the SDK, you'll need to install **CMake** and **Ninja** on your PC.

If you plan to develop real-time capable applications (RTApps), you might need to [install a compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/development-environment-windows#m4-toolchain) for the embedded processor and [set up hardware to display output from the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/development-environment-windows#set-up-hardware-to-display-output).

Both Quickstarts "[Build an RTapp on cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/qs-real-time-app-cli)" and "[Build an RTApp with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/qs-real-time-application)" require that you use CMake at some stage and those are the supported methods.

**Update:** New documentation improvements will be done soon to address the option of using a different build system to cmake and "yes" it should work as you suggest.